Should we block the [disputed-review-audits] tag on this site?
The tag disputed-review-audits here on this site was previously used for reporting bad audits in the review queues.
However, questions about specific review audits are, by definition, site-specific, as the only actions that can be taken in response to them are for users there to take actions against the post being audited (e.g., close an off-topic question that got picked as a known-good audit) or for site moderators to lift any incorrect automatic review suspensions.
Most of this tag's uses are from back in the pre-MSO-MSE split days when this site also served as Stack Overflow's per-site meta - users used this tag to report specific bad audits on Stack Overflow.
The only type of site-specific questions accepted here today (that aren't translation or localization issues) are questions specific to this site, Meta Stack Exchange. This site doesn't have review audits enabled, so the tag cannot be validly used in combination with the tag meta to report bad audits here.
There might be questions about bad review audits in general, but the extended description of the tag explicitly states that the tag is only for reporting specific bad audits and that the review-audits tag should be used instead for posts that aren't about a specific given audit.
To summarize, the disputed-review-audits tag is explicitly defined for asking about a topic that is no longer on-topic here on this site.
Should we block the tag to prevent its further use? I think it's the best course of action since there is still value in categorizing past disputed audit reports here from the pre-split era (meaning it shouldn't be burninated). There may also be value in categorizing general questions about bad review audits, but the tag's name also implies one is disputing a specific review audit, and I personally feel that the general review-audits tag is sufficient for these.

While contesting a specific review audit would be off-topic for here, there are some question with [disputed-review-audits] that would be on-topic. Some of the posts with that tag are [feature-request]s related to wrong review audits. Some of them are suggestions on how to decrease the number of wrong review audits or how to decrease the chance someone fails a review audit when they meant to do the correct action.
Other posts with that tag are about large categories of posts which are incorrectly ending up as review audits. If such a category is problematic for multiple sites, then that would belong here. Another category of posts which are fine for MSE are asking about the systems for reporting review audits, how review audits are judged, or reporting potential bugs (ex. you passed/failed for performing a neutral action. For example, if you failed a review audit for showing vote counts.)
I disagree that the tag's name implies disputing a specific audit. When I first saw that tag (before reading the wiki/usage guidance), I thought it was about the system of disputing an audit or about what happens to audits which some mod disputes.
Perhaps, though, the tag description should be changed to what questions are acceptable on MSE (and with a note telling people to ask about specific audits on the per-site meta). Also, I've now used up an entire days worth of close votes trying to close the still open questions with this tag that don't belong here (and I only got like 40% the way through because most of them don't belong here). Some cleanup is definetly needed.

Personally, I don't think it's worthwhile to lump together general questions about bad review audits together with older reports about specific bad audits. I think it's OK to just tag them as only [tag:review-audits], but if the distinction from questions about audits that don't have to do with bad review audits is important, then I think a new tag should be created for them while the older tag [tag:disputed-review-audits] should be blocked as a historical tag.
